# Comparing two xdocuments for equality

Tags: comparison, linq-to-xml

I need to compare two XDocument objects together. Unfortunately there are known differences between them, so a direct object comparison wont work. What i need is a way to recurse  through every element and attribute of the xml document and compare their respective values, whilst ignoring the ones that are known to be different.

I know the names of the attributes that are known to be different (time date fields amongst others). What is the best strategy for achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

if the XDocument objects are structurally equivalent, you could simply walk through the two hierarchies (using Descendant property, you can simply iterate). Then for each element returned, you can enumerate attributes.

at each step, if you get some element mismatch, you already know that your documents are different, else check attributes, skipping those that you know to be 'ignorable', continue iteration until end of Descendant collection.